# Create a method which create dynamic expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I want to create a method which return dictionary like below. But, I want being generic method which paremerters ara EntityType and columnNameList. I want to call like this,

My method calling:

```
CreateColumnMap<Student>(new List<string>{"Name","Surname","Age"});
```

My return value

```
 var columnsMap = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Student, object>>>()
                    {
                      ["Name"] = v => v.Name,
                      ["Surname"] = v => v.Surname,
                      ["Age"] = v => v.Age
                    };
```

Student.cs

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
}
```

I started function like below. But i can't complete. How can i complete "???" part.

```
public Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>> CreateColumnMap<T>(List<string> columNameList)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>>();
    foreach (var columnName in columNameList)
    {
        //??????
        dictionary.Add(); //????????????????????
        //??????
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference [Creating Expression Trees by Using the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx#Anchor_1)

Use the `Expression` class and its static factory methods to manually build the desired expression based on the provided member name from the generic argument type.

For example, the following uses the `Parameter` and `Property` factory methods to manually build the expression tree nodes for the lambda expression `v => v.PropertyName`

```
Expression<Func<TModel, object>> GetPropertyExpression<TModel>(string propertyName) {
    // Manually build the expression tree for 
    // the lambda expression v => v.PropertyName.

    // (TModel v) =>
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "v");
    // (TModel v) => v.PropertyName
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

    var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, object>>(property, parameter);
    return expression;
}
```

You can then apply the above

```
public Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>> CreateColumnMap<T>(List<string> columNameList) {
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>>();
    foreach (var columnName in columNameList) {            
        dictionary[columnName] = GetPropertyExpression<T>(columnName);
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi. That was what I was looking for. It worked.